# TED talk API or workaround for data access

Tags: web-services, api, blackberry

It is my understanding that TED likely is not looking at making a BlackBerry App. I have a few frameworks I've created already for parsing various types of API's/feeds/services and would like to know if there is a way for a third party developer to make a TED app. I've heard mention of an API via the Googles but cannot find it.

Comment: Official TED APIs are out and are available at http://developer.ted.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is quite old, but I just came across it. I was searching for an API for TED Talks as well, but was unable to find one. They have announced that they'll open up the site with an API, but I don't know when.

Instead, I decided to use the XML RSS feed, which is easily parsable. It's only usable for the latest talks and you naturally can't do any server-side filtering, but if that's good enough for you, you should definitely check out the feed:

http://www.ted.com/talks/rss

There's also the higher definition version of that feed:

http://feeds.feedburner.com/TedtalksHD?fmt=xml

Comment: Thats the best I came up with as well, and then abandoned my efforts. Thanks though.

Comment: What about the subtitles ? For non-english speakers, that will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There is an unofficial API for all ted talks details (gathered from youtube and ted.com)

its updated weekly with the data

http://market.mashape.com/bestapi/ted

supports:

- get talks by name
- get talks by speaker
- get talks by description
- get talks by transcript / search transcript

and looks like they publish more end-points from time to time

Answer (score 1):

If you guys are still looking for something, I just open-sourced about 5400 hundred TED talks (TEDx, TED, TEDEd). Check it out and build something cool.

https://github.com/saranyan/TED-talks